# PHP file upload does not work in XAMPP

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp

I'm trying to upload an xml file using an Android app I developed.

To do this, I used a free hosting space, and it works great. But now, I want to upload files to one of my pc's folders, using xampp as a web server.

The problem is that when I try to upload files here something goes wrong.
I am sure my php code is good, because it works with the hosting service I have my website on, so I only changed the path, as you can see below.

For hosting service:

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = '/membri/cendav/gestione_magazzino/ExportData/';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'];
    $pic_name = $_FILES['transactions']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
}
else{
    echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
}
?>
```

Now, the code for xampp, which is the same:

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = 'exportdata/';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'];
    $pic_name = $_FILES['transactions']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
}
else{
    echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
}
?>
```

As you can see, I only changed the `$uploads_dir`. The path from where I access the file `upload.php`, from my application `http://10.0.0.202:1024/Warepad/`.

I also changed the permissions of the `exportdata/` folder, to everyone, but it still doesn't work.

P.S. I know there's a ton of these issues, but I still can't find what the problem is.

Comment: Can you add the error output to your question? `error_reporting(-1);` will do the trick.

Comment: Here it is: `10.0.0.190 - - [02/Oct/2017:09:21:16 +0200] "POST /Warepad/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 609 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; SM-T585 Build/NRD90M)"`

Comment: That's an access log. Try looking your error log file or add error_reporting top of your code.

Comment: did you increase upload file size in php.ini?

Comment: No, I didn't touch the php.ini

Comment: But as you can see I don't thing that is the problem .`post_max_size = 128M`

Comment: your mobile application connect to right host? my meaning is that you put the right ip address in mobile app?and your folder permission is 777?

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: check this url: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/9319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now it seems to work. It's strange, because the file upload.php is the same, and I haven't changed anything else!

```
?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'])) {
    $uploads_dir = 'exportdata/';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['transactions']['tmp_name'];
    $pic_name = $_FILES['transactions']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name);
}
else{
    echo "File not uploaded successfully.";
}
?>
```

The Android app, now, is able to upload file correctly, but if I try to upload from an html form, it still doesn't work.
Here's the html code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
    Invia questo file: <input name="transactions" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Invia File">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form action="fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```